# Python BeautifulSoup find_all in a for loop of csv

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble on a project I am working on.

I have a CSV file that has all of the urls in the first column.

My script below currently pulls in and iterates through each row but then as soon as it trys to find_all it readys the following error:
IndexError: list index out of range.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

with open('1.csv', "r", newline="") as inFile, open("1output.csv", "w", newline="") as outFile:
    next(inFile)
    reader = csv.reader(inFile)
    writer = csv.writer(outFile)
    for row in reader:
        subURL = row[0]

        # Parse the HTML from the website
        URL = 'https://www.example.com/{}'.format(subURL)
        page = requests.get(URL)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

        # find iframe on webpage and get the src of the iframe
        iframeDesc = soup.find_all('iframe')[0]
        pageDesc = requests.get(iframeDesc['src'])
        soupDesc = BeautifulSoup(pageDesc.content, 'html.parser')

        # Get Description from iframe Desc
        itemDesc = soupDesc.find_all('div', id="div_01")
```

Error occurs on this line:

```
iframeDesc = soup.find_all('iframe')[0]
```

Comment: maybe the site doesn't have iframe. share the link of the site

Comment: The website has an iframe and the iframe selector code works when not embded in a for loop

Comment: Thanks Joshua, The URL was incorrect there was no Iframe you was right

Comment: Sure. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be various motivations to your problem, let me introduce you the most likely.

1. **Wrong pattern**: in this case the exception is normal since you are asking BeautifulSoup to return you something that does not occur in the document
2. **Typo**: the easiest one, maybe a wrong letter is not allowing you to get the desired node?

Moreover, I suspect that you are looking for the wrong node in the tree. In fact, this happens a lot when using BS because you are basically going down in the DOM and missing a tag is really likely to occur. Just place some prints around your code to see what's going on those lines.

Comment: Thank you. Currently when I print the html parser it shows me the page content with the iframe.when I remove the [0] at the end of the findall the script works but then when I comment the next line in to the code it gives me a different error which is:
TypeError: list indices must be intergers or slices, not str.

Comment: This happens because it returns you a list of objects which you are indexing using the 'src' string. Try to print iframeDesc and check if the list is not empty, if this is the case you can take your object and access its 'src' property.

Comment: Thank you I found out that the url was wrong thanks for your help